# React, how to add class to nodeList childs?

Tags: reactjs

So, like in my question, i have a `nodeList` collection. And it look like that:
[image]

I dont even try becouse i'm not abble to get single element.

Code that generete that:

```
const getNode = text => OptionSelectRef.current.querySelector(text);
const setOption = getNode(".blogs-list-items");
var children = setOption.childNodes[0];
console.log(children)
```

so, what i need to do is add class to 3rd and 5th element... Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: accessing DOM directly is against React way for doing things. Is there any reason you cannot do that in React-way?

Comment: dont have access to code it have to be HOC

Answer (score 1):

You can first get your `wrapperRef`'s childrens, then loop through them and if their index matches your desired index, add the class to them.

You can take a look at this example

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Get wrapper's childrens
    const childrens = Array.from(wrapperRef.current.children);
    // Loop through children
    childrens.forEach((children, idx) => {
      // If children's current index match 2 or 4
      if ([2, 4].some(matchingIdx => idx === matchingIdx)) {
        // Add class to that children
        children.classList.add('new-class');
      }
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div ref={wrapperRef} className="blog-list-items__elements">
      <div className="blog-list-items"></div>
      <div className="blog-list-items"></div>
      <div className="blog-list-items"></div>
      <div className="blog-list-items"></div>
      <div className="blog-list-items"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find node using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);`

you need to make sure that this will refer to your upper div.

Than you can find child nodes of the div using`.childNodes[2] && .childNodes[4]`. then apply className to node using `.childNodes[2].classList.add('new-class') && .childNodes[4].classList.add('new-class')`